# Preload blocks the entire render phase

Tags: css, preload

I have this simple example of preload just to see how it works. Preload fetches resources without blocking browser's rendering. But this is not the case. The script down below is always executed after fonts are been downloaded. You can check this by changing network connection to slow in dev tools.

Why is this happening?

**Iam using the latest chrome**

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="preload" onload="this.rel = 'stylesheet'" as="style" href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,500,700,900,800|Material+Icons'>

</head>
<body>
  Hello
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        console.log('Loaded')
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've setup a simple test case [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nsurfeyc/)

The test case is not very different from your original code, just changed `<link>`:

```
<link rel="preload" onload="console.log('loaded stylesheet')" rel="stylesheet" as="style" href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,500,700,900,800|Material+Icons'>
```

The script was executed before the stylesheet has been fetched for the first load, for all subsequent loads the script was executed after stylesheet has been fetched. For subsequent requests stylesheet *should* be cached in the browser and no further fetching should be required:

[image: console log]

Comment: Doesnt work. To me i see everytimr first loaded stylesheet and then loaded